# custom layout has space in left side

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

The problem is that i have back-arrow along with an ImageView with a profile image as WhatsApp has in its chat layout.
I want this back arrow to extreme left of action bar and image should be go with back arrow. just like whatsapp.

[image]

my xml code is attached here

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_back_post_comment"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/navigation_back_post_comment"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_back_post_comment"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_author_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_account_circle_40" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_author"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="someauthor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="@dimen/email_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="someauthor@email.com" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/star_layout_inflate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star_cmnt_inflate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_num_stars_cmnt_inflate"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="7" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your back button code with this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_back_post_comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/post_author_layout_inflate"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />
```

Explanation:

Instead of setting layout_width to a fixed width, you should set it to wrap_content. If this still doesn't satisfy your requirements you can set android:paddingLeft="*Some negative value*" and android:paddingRight="*Some negative value*" or android:paddingStart="*Some negative value*" and android:paddingEnd="*Some negative value*" (for right-to-left support). Try experimenting with different values to find your optimal configuration.

Comment: a negative value could work but is this not a wrong way to do as on other device of android it will diffrently @HarisGusic

Comment: @Uttam Meerwal If you set the padding to a dp value then it will scale accordingly on different devices. For example if your image is 24dp and you set android:paddingLeft="-8dp" then 16dp of the image will be visible, on every device. An alternative solution would be to crop the source image. I presume that you are using the original back icon that google have provided, so it has some left and right padding in it. You can try to edit the image to remove the padding. Note however that you will have to edit all the different versions of the image for different densities.